# Git stash twice

Tags: git, git-stash

I had to quickly switch git branches, so I ran `git stash`, but I had to run it again because one of my files needed editing.

So I've run `git stash` twice, and I'm ready to go back to editing my files. I ran `git stash apply` but I'm not convinced that all of the files I had stashed were unstashed. Is there anything I can do? Any way to check?

When I run `git stash show`, I just see the last of my two git stashes.

Is there anyway to show all `git stashes`?

Comment: `git stash list`. If you made two stashes, then call `git stash pop` twice.

Comment: Hi, you fixed it! You should put it as an answer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 255, accepted):

You can get a list of all stashes with

```
git stash list
```

which will show you something like

```
stash@{0}: WIP on dev: 1f6f8bb Commit message A
stash@{1}: WIP on master: 50cf63b Commit message B
```

If you made two stashes, then just call `git stash pop` twice. As opposed to `git stash apply`, `pop` applies and *removes* the latest stash.

You can also reference a specific stash, e.g.

```
git stash show stash@{1}
```

or

```
git stash apply stash@{1}
```

Comment: If you want to `git stash pop` twice because you want both stashes in the same commit but you encounter "error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:" on your 2nd `git stash pop`, then you can: 1) `git stash pop`, 2) `git add .`, and 3) `git stash pop`.

Comment: This helped me. I needed to do "git stash" and then "git stash --all" to stash some new untracked files. Doing git stash pop twice was not working. I only got the later stash back.

Answer (score 14):

I came across this situation, I did two stashes and
**git stash pop**
just unstashed last stash. So I did

```
git stash list

git stash pop stash@{1}
```

This unstashed my first stash and I could see all my changes back!

Answer (score 6):

You asked a few different questions in post, and other respondents gave good answers to some of them. The one that seems most important but hasn't been answered is this:

*>>I'm not convinced that all of the files I had stashed were unstashed. Is there anything I can do? Any way to check?*

### Compare stash to local tree

I think what you want to do is compare the stash to your local [working tree](https://www.theserverside.com/video/Understand-the-Git-working-tree-status-command-for-easy-DVCS). You can put the -p switch on the stash command and you're good:

```
git stash show -p
```

If there's a particular one you're after, just use its [git stash name](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-to-use-a-git-stash-name-for-an-easy-pop-or-apply) or id from the stash list:

```
git stash show -p stash@{3}
```

### Maybe use the diff?

If you're really interested in pushing your git skills, you could always go for a diff. To see the difference between what's in the stash and whats checked into the HEAD on the master branch the following diff could be used:

```
git diff stash@ master
```

Another neat command to show you changes for elements in the stash history that might come in handy is --stat:

```
git stash list --stat
```

But I think the simple answer is the right answer. Just use the -p switch and you'll likely see if the [stash you shelved](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-to-git-shelve-changes-and-save-local-files-with-stash) has been popped back.

```
git stash show -p stash@{3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case :

If you are on VSCode Terminal and try `git stash apply stash@{1}` you can have an error: unknow switch `e'

You can do `git stash apply 'stash@{1}'` with quotes